# Complex Typescript Interface with Objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface defined as:

```
export interface Address {
    addressType: {
        house?: {
            streetAddress: string,
            city: string,
            zip: string,
        },
        apartment?: {
            streetAddress: "",
            unitNumber: "",
            city: "",
            zip: "",
            buildingName?: "",
        },
    }
    instructions?: string;
}
```

Then in my Typescript file of my component, I am defining a house address:

```
address: Address;

constructor() {

    this.address.addressType = {
      house: {
        streetAddress: "1 test",
        city: "test city",
        zip: "92222",
      }
    }        
    console.log(this.address);
}
```

Though when I log the address to the console, I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'addressType' of undefined
```

I thought I was setting the addressType in the constructor. Is there a more efficient way to do what I'm doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize `this.address` before you can set its addressType:

```
constructor() {

    this.address = {
      addressType: {
        house: {
          streetAddress: "1 test",
          city: "test city",
          zip: "92222",
        }
      }
    };        
    console.log(this.address);
}
```

Comment: What's the reason for downvote? This is the only answer suggesting to initialise the whole `address` and not creating unnecessary objects and overriding them like other answers do.

Answer (score 3):

First initialize your `address` to refer to an object. This will serve a memory for your object and then you can initialize nested properties.

```
address: Address = { addressType: {} };

constructor() {

    this.address.addressType = {
      house: {
        streetAddress: "1 test",
        city: "test city",
        zip: "92222",
      }
    }        
    console.log(this.address);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize your `address` property becuase anotate any property with type don't give a value and it 's initil value in `undefined`.

You can iniltalize you property like this

```
address: Address = { addressType: {} };
```

But I think the best approtue here is to create a class base on the Address Interface

```
export interface IAddress {
  addressType: {
    house?: {
      streetAddress: string,
      city: string,
      zip: string,
    },
    apartment?: {
      streetAddress: "",
      unitNumber: "",
      city: "",
      zip: "",
      buildingName?: "",
    },
  }
  instructions?: string;
}

class Address implements IAddress {
  addressType: { house?: { streetAddress: string; city: string; zip: string; }; 
  apartment?: { streetAddress: ""; unitNumber: ""; city: ""; zip: ""; buildingName?: ""; }; };
  instructions?: string;
  constructor() {
    this.addressType = {}; 
  }
}
```

and you can use it like this

```
address: Address = new Address();
```

> house property of addressType is `undefined`

```
// this will throw an error can't read streetAddress of undefined
{{address.addressType.house.streetAddress}}
```

in order to solve the error above you can initialize `house` same like `addressType`

```
  constructor() {
    this.addressType = {}; 
    this.addressType.house = {}
  }
```